# Are all recent multi-core processors 64-bit?

Tags: cpu

I think that my intel core-duo processor in my 4 year old laptop is 32-bit.

But since the core 2 duo introduction, can I assume that for intel at least, multicore processors will all run a 64-bit OS?

Is there a reference table anywhere listing common CPU chips and their properties?

Answer (score 6):

Multicore Atom N330 is 32bit even though it just came out :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_microprocessors

Comment: I have the E6600. The list does not state if it's 64-bit capable -- this must be so obvious to everyone that they don't bother to state. I'm pretty sure it is. The list also does not tell me if the models support hardware DEP, the wolfdale might be the first one with this, but not sure.

Comment: Just learned they all have hardware DEP.

Comment: The list does have E6600 under the "64-bit processors: Intel 64 - Core microarchitecture" section.  So it is 64 bit.